# Re size div having DOJO table with window

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have a div which holds a DOJO table. The problem is, when I resize the browser, the DOJO table is not re-sized. How do I re-size it?? This is my div

```
    <div id="grid1" jsid="grid1" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" query="{ name: '*' }"
        data-dojo-props="plugins:{ pagination:{pageSizes: ['10', '25', '50', '100'],
        description: true, sizeSwitch: true, pageStepper: true, gotoButton: true, position: 'bottom', maxPageStep: 7}}, rowsPerPage:10"
                    style="height: 300px; width: 930px;"></div>
    </div>
```

This is the DOJO table.

```
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter");
    dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    var gridLayout = [ 
    {
    name : "Capacity",
    classes : "title",
    field : "capacityKVA",
    width : "90px"
}, {
    name : "Date & Time",
    classes : "title",
    field : "date",
    width : "140px"
}, {
    name : 'Status',
    classes : "title",
    field : "statusMessage",
    fields : [ 'statusMessage', 'statusMessageColor' ],
    formatter : formatLink1,
    width : "140px"
}];
```

Comment: Here's a similar question: [Automatically Resize dojo dijit.Grid widget when it's parent container resizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870199/automatically-resize-dojo-dijit-grid-widget-when-its-parent-container-resizes) and its first answer matches your case very well.